# Angular core providers like PLATFORM_ID

Tags: angular, angular-providers

In value-based providers (tokens), we have something like this (in the module):

```
const CONFIG = 'CONFIG';
providers: [
    {
        provide: CONFIG,
        useValue: myConfigObj,
    },
```

Because we defined the provider in module, in a service we can do this:

```
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(CONFIG) config) {
    console.log(config);
}
```

But when we want to access `PLATFORM_ID` like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId) {
```

We don't define `PLATFORM_ID` in the module's provider. In which module this is defined? And what is the `useValue` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered this for you on the Angular Community Discord server, but I'm not sure you saw that.

By calling `platformBrowserDynamic()` (or `platformDynamicServer()` in case of an @Angular/universal app) in main.ts, an injector is created which is configured by `PlatformModule`. `PLATFORM_ID` is provided here.

The value is a string: `'browser'` (or `'server'` for a universal app).

You can read more about the platform injector (which is a parent of the root injector) here: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#platform-injector

edit: By request, the links to the source code: It's provided here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.2.9/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform_providers.ts#L27, then it get's passed into a createPlatformFactory: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.2.9/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/platform-browser-dynamic.ts#L29 where the Injector is created with the passed in providers: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bafec59b33819b8a47eb9723f8014618c9f1b991/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L181-L186

Comment: Thank you. I'm seeing now. Would you please add all links you mentioned in the Discord server?

Comment: @VahidNajafi I added the links to the source code.